# Why can't I use the count method of list?

Tags: python, count

I use the method split() of the string class and supposedly it returns a list, but it isn't a common list because I can't use list methods like count()

I've tried to use the count method of list but it doesn't work.

```
def do_prueba(self, s):

    lista=s.split()
    len=lista.count()
    print(len)
```

I want to know the length of that list. I'm new to Python sorry.

Comment: You are confusing what `count` does. `mylist.count(x)` returns the number of occurences of `x` in the list `mylist`. What you want is `len`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't providing an argument to `count`. Just use the `len` function to get the length (not to be confused with the variable you named `len`, which you shouldn't do as it overrides the built-in):

```
def do_prueba(self, s):
    lista=s.split()
    print(len(lista))
```